# AWS Open search in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, opensearch

I need to implement AWS open search in laravel 8 did any one have idea how can we get this? any reference link or tutorial ? does any one have doing same before ?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented OpenSearch with a couple of projects on Laravel 9 recently.
Here is the instruction on how to install OpenSearch:
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/install/index/

And this is the really simple custom Laravel Scout engine you may use:
https://github.com/romangrinev/laravel-openseach-engine

Answer (score 0):

For AWS open search in Laravel 8.x you can refer my custom package based on Laravel Scout engine.

https://github.com/tris-nm/laravel-scout-opensearch-engine

It's work well for my project with Amazon OpenSearch Service version 1.2